# MySQL: Which is better, Select then Update, or UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

Which is better, doing a select first and then an update. Or rather all in one like this:

```
UPDATE items set status = 'NEW' 
    where 
      itemid in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) AND
      status = 'OLD' AND
      9387487484 >= itemdate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every optimisation available to a `SELECT` statement will be applied during the processing of an `UPDATE` statement (if, as I suspect, this is your concern). Therefore, just issue a single `UPDATE`.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update-speed.html

Comment: further more from mysql 5.6 you can use `EXPLAIN` on `UPDATE` statements (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) so you could compare the results of the EXPLAIN on the select and update which should be the same in rows scanned and indexes used